# Parsing two JSON files

Tags: python-3.x

I have two `JSON files`, absolutely identical in structure, only they have different values.
My code, with which I parse one file and save the data to a `CSV file`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json

filename_json = "/root/test.json"

with open(filename_json, "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
    file_csv = open("/tmp/tmp.csv", "w")
    file_csv.write("Source IP;Source Port;Destination IP;Destination Port \n")

    for file in data:
        destination_ip = file["destination_ip"]
        source_ip = file["source_ip"]
        source_port = file["source_port"]
        destination_port = file["destination_port"]
        source_port = str(source_port)
        destination_port = str(destination_port)
        
        inference = (source_ip + ";" + source_port + ";" + destination_ip + ";" +  destination_port + "\n")

        file_csv.write(inference)
    file_csv.close()
```

... and I have another JSON file, it is the same, i.e. this parsing is suitable for it.

Could you tell me please, how do I make sure that the result from the `first JSON file` is written to the `CSV file` `first` in the `first row` (of course, after the column names), and the first result from the `second JSON file` is written in the `second line` to the CSV file. In general, the result should be such a `CSV file`:

| Source IP | Source Port | Destination IP | Destination Port | there is no such column, just a description so that it is clear from which JSON and how the strings should be written |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.1 | 25 | 192.168.1.2 | 25 | the `first` disassembled block from the `first` JSON file |
| 192.168.1.2 | 25 | 192.168.1.1 | 25 | the `first` disassembled block from the `second` JSON file |
| 192.168.1.9 | 21 | 192.168.1.8 | 21 | the `second` disassembled block from the `first` JSON file |
| 192.168.1.8 | 21 | 192.168.1.9 | 21 | the `second` disassembled block from the `second` JSON file |

and so on, arrange in this order.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look on csv File Reading: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

e.g:

```
import json
import csv


j1 = json.loads('[{"c1": "bla", "c2": 5}, {"c1": "bla1", "c2": 6}, {"c1": "bla2", "c2": 7}]')
j2 = json.loads('[{"c1": "blub", "c2": 1}, {"c1": "blub", "c2": 2}, {"c1": "blub", "c2": 3}]')


with open("./yourfile.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["c1", "C2"])
    for i in range(len(j1)):
        csv_writer.writerow([j1[i]['c1'],j1[i]['c2']])
        csv_writer.writerow([j2[i]['c1'],j2[i]['c2']])
```

if the json files have different length you can take the longer one for range command and do some try except inside the loop:

```
import json
import csv


j1 = json.loads('[{"c1": "bla", "c2": 5}, {"c1": "bla1", "c2": 6}, {"c1": "bla2", "c2": 7}]')
j2 = json.loads('[{"c1": "blub", "c2": 1}, {"c1": "blub", "c2": 2}, {"c1": "blub", "c2": 3}, {"c1": "blub", "c2": 9}]')


with open("./yourfile.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["c1", "C2"])
    for i in range(max([len(j1),len(j2)])):
        try:
            csv_writer.writerow([j1[i]['c1'],j1[i]['c2']])
        except IndexError:
            print('First json file out of data')
        try:
            csv_writer.writerow([j2[i]['c1'],j2[i]['c2']])
        except IndexError:
            print('Second json file out of data')
```

Another way by using pandas could be manipulate the index of input files and sort them after concatination:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_json('[{"c1": "bla", "c2": 1}, {"c1": "bla1", "c2": 3}, {"c1": "bla2", "c2": 5}, {"c1": "bla3", "c2": 7}]')
df2 = pd.read_json('[{"c1": "blub", "c2": 2}, {"c1": "blub1", "c2": 4}, {"c1": "blub2", "c2": 6}, {"c1": "blub3", "c2": 8}, {"c1": "blub4", "c2": 10}]')

df1.index = np.arange(0, (len(df1))*2, 2)
df2.index = np.arange(1, (len(df2))*2, 2)
output = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()


output.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me that this is not exactly what I need.

Comment: Yes, sorry its not the finished solution. It is just an example how you can write row wise to an csv file.
Propably there are multiple ways to reach your target.
You can think about to load both json files parallel and iterate thorugh them at same time and in each iteration you write a row with data from first file and then a row from second file.

Comment: I have edit my post more specific

Comment: Great, thanks. what you need

Comment: Could you also tell me, please, I have encountered such a problem, if my `first JSON` has `10` blocks, and the `second JSON` has `11` blocks, then the last `11th` blob of the second `JSON file` will not be placed in the `CSV file`. But if I do a range check, and into the loop `for i in range(len(j1)):` i substitute `j2` instead of `j1`, then the error appears: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: You can handle this by doing some try except: look at edit of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238693/discussion-between-schulzjo-and-alex-rebell).